# How can I open a subset of a large (35MB) .xlsx file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, openoffice-calc, parsing, gnumeric

I have Ubuntu 10.04 running on a Dell Optiplex with 4GB of memory and two 3.16GHz processors.

I received a 35MB spreadsheet.  It opened in Gnumeric after 5 minutes with errors, and it hasn't opened in Open Office (killed after 20 min.) even after I gave the "soffice" process top priority (niceness = -20).

What is the best way to deal with such a file?  Is it possible to extract a subset of the first few hundred lines so that I can work out the script that I will need to use to parse the entire file?

*update:*

The command line function `ssconvert BigFile.xlsx BigFile.csv` produced the same errors as Gnumeric (unsurprising because Gnumeric uses `ssconvert`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably but you'll need some manual work.

xslx files are in fact ZIP files with XML data in them. SO just unpack the file and have a look inside. The format isn't something a sane mind will easily understand but it should be possible to open the sheet files, look for the `Row` elements and strip everything after the first few hundred.

Alternatively, you can try to open the file with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/); just give Java 1GB of RAM and it might work.